# Laravel 4 artisan migration unable to connect to remote mysql db [HY000] [1450] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mypc' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-connection, laravel-4

EDIT: I finally realised artisan is trying to connect to my machine instead of the remote database host specified in config. I assumed it would retrieve the hosts address along with the username and password. I'll try to specify the host's address on commandline and post back.

EDIT 2: I found the problem. Technical support for the host mislead me to my first edit. The problem was a mismatch in the password between a '1' and an 'l'. Sorry to have wasted your time.

I'm developing a Laravel 4 web app and I'm trying to execute migrations from sentry into a remote mysql database. I have been able to connect via phpmyadmin using the same credentials stored into laravel without any hassle, but artisan won't work.

Here's artisan command and output:

```
$ php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry

[PDOException]                                                               
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'mypc' (using password: YES)                                                          

migrate [--bench[="..."]] [--database[="..."]] [--path[="..."]] [--package[="..."]] [-- pretend] [--seed]
```

Laravel connection config:

```
'default' => 'mysql',
[...]
'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'hostname.example.com',
        'database'  => 'mydb',
        'username'  => 'myuser',
        'password'  => 'supersecretpassword',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
   ),
```

I don't have mysql installed locally, just apache, php and phpmyadmin. My box is archlinux and I don't have access to the remote host.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant rights to that user on that host (this is the machine from where you connect):

```
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO myuser@mypc IDENTIFIED by 'supersecretpassword';
```

Comment: I don't have access to that host in order to change that and phpmyadmin connects perfectly using the same user and password. If it was a matter of permissions, wouldn't phpmyadmin also fail to connect? They are both accessing from the same machine to a remote database.

Comment: If they are both accessing from the same machine then yes ur right. Are you sure you are using the same username and password ?

Comment: try running this query from the pma `select user,host from mysql.user`

Comment: Just realised it isn't trying to connect to the remote host but the local machine bypassing the config. Thanks for your help, I edited the question and will try specifying the address on cmd-line.

Comment: then its clear you need to create that user on your local machine and set the grants for it